# hide scroll bar not scrolling in material UI box tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

```
<Box
            paddingX={4}
            mt={3}
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              width: 600,
              height: 220,
              border: "1px solid #e1e1e1",
              overflow: 'auto',
              '&::-webkit-scrollbar': { display: 'none' }
            //   '&::-webkit-scrollbar': { width : 0 },
            }}
          >
```

> Here is a piece of code i tried but nothing happens

**i need to hide scroll bar**

Comment: Like with `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: with this scrollbar hides butt unable to scroll

Comment: well, your question says *instead of scrolling*

Comment: sorry its my mistake